# Eclipse debug (use F5) in servlet and in Main application

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, log4j

I have a Class named Mo.
Mo has a static function as below:

```
public static void logsomething(String s)
```

The body of the logsomething use the log4j(jar). That's not a problem.

I also have a Main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Mo.logsomething("sth");
    }
```

I called the Mo.logsomething() in main. It's OK. No error.

But I call this Mo.logsomething("sth") in Servlet doGet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            Mo.logsomething("sss");

        response.getWriter().println("<h1>hello</h1>");
    }
```

Get an exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout

So it's weird. I try to debug to see what happend.
When the debug cursor is on the line:Mo.logsomething("sss");
I press F5 to step in the code.
But I get the error:source not found.

What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not writing what application server you use. But your error is likely to be an classpath error.

The problem is that your application server could not find the `Log4J` library.

Usually this problem can be solved by putting the `Log4J` jar file into the `WEB-INF/lib/` directory of your web application and deploy that application again.

Comment: I copy the jar file to the WEB-INF/lib/. but no effect. Any idea?

Comment: @roast_soul Have you deployed again? What server do you use?

Comment: It's the classpath error, I add the jar path to the run configuration->classpath. It works.